# Conditional Left Join MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

How can I apply condition in `LEFT JOIN`?

### Query

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col2
FROM tab1 a 
LEFT JOIN tab2 b 
ON IF (a.col1='1', a.col2=b.col2, a.col3=b.col2)
```

explaination.

IF a.col1='1' then join a.col2 with table b column b.col2
ELSE
join a.col3 with same table b column b.col2

I don't prefer to do double LEFT JOIN like, 
LEFT JOIN tab2 b ON a.col2=b.col2
LEFT JOIN tab2 c ON a.col3=c.col2
Because I have to do subsequent left joins on the result of above left joins.

Any Solutions ??????

Comment: Ok, I'll bite... what's wrong with the query you're showing besides the column names being a bit ambigious?

Comment: I think what you want to Google is `CASE()`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16456/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it works doing it in the `ON`-section but logically I would rather put it in the `WHERE`-section anyway.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
  FROM tab1 a 
  LEFT JOIN tab2 b
 WHERE (col1  = '1' AND a.col2 = b.col2)
    OR (col1 != '1' AND a.col3 = b.col2);
```

Also, since this is a `LEFT JOIN` all values in tab2 can be null and in that case neither `a.col2 = b.col2` or `a.col3 = b.col2` will be true so in effect this is the same as a normal `JOIN`

Comment: I appreciate it, My issue is, I have do subsequent left join on the result of the first Left join, So this may not work. Thank you anyway Andreas .....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.col1,a.col2,b.col1,b.col2 
 FROM tab1 a 
  LEFT JOIN tab2 b on a.col1=b.col2
 left join tab3 c on b.col1=c.col3 

  left join work only when data must avail on left side table . so you have to chose table on that manner
```

Comment: Certainly, The issue is, It already has the value on left side table...but the join is dependent upon a.col1 Value, If a.col1=1, then the join will be a.col2=b.col2........Else.....a.col3=b.col2 ................. According to the condition the left side column will be changed,....the right side column b.col2 will be static.